# What does a comma mean in a makefile definition?

Tags: makefile

What does a comma mean in this makefile rule (variable definition?)? e.g.

```
target1,SRCS = foo.c bar.c
target2,SRCS = bat.c baz.c
```

It seems to define a variable, SRCS, that's associated with a specific target, but I'm not sure. Obviously there are more make definitions involved, but it's a complex makefile infrastructure and I wouldn't know where to begin to understand the larger context. The make is generic; the makefile is used under both clearmake and GNU make.

What this does in our make system is build target1 using the given source files. Effectively it's like

```
SRCS = foo.c bar.c
target1: $(SRCS)
```

Honestly I feel like this is a simple question but I don't recall running across this syntax in my many years of experience and had a frustrating time searching for it. I tried looking up "," in the GNU make manual, and did a full-text search for the word "comma", and a few web searches as well but no luck.

Comment: Most likely there is some code elsewhere in the makefile that has something like `$@,SRCS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a symbol, but a sneaky one. GNU Make allows a comma to be the part of a Make variable's name.

Comment: Oh that's wicked!

Comment: In fact there are very, very few characters which are not legal in a make variable name.